# How to translate this bootstrap code to react-bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm evaluation react-bootstrap and was wondering how you would translate the following bootstrap code to react-bootstrap

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2">
      <!--Sidebar content-->
    </div>
    <div class="span10">
      <!--Body content-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to change the classes to the appropriate ones

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the library react-bootstrap for this code,this library helps you with the bootstrap components like the Modal or an Accordion.

Anyway if you really need to render that elements through React JS, just change the HTML `class` attribute for the React attribute `className`.

Hope Helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div className="container-fluid">
    <div className="row-fluid">
      <div className="span2">
        /*Sidebar content*/
      </div>
      <div className="span10">
        /*Body content*/
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

That's all you need to do.  Replace "class" with "className" and then insert it into a React component.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook provide a JSX compiler to help you in your task so use it ! 
Don't do that on your own because they are a lot of changes to do manually sometimes when using different attributes, styles...
https://facebook.github.io/react/html-jsx.html

The result is the following :

```
  <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row-fluid">
          <div className="span2">
            {/*Sidebar content*/}
          </div>
          <div className="span10">
            {/*Body content*/}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

It can even create the component for you :

```
var NewComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (

      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row-fluid">
          <div className="span2">
            {/*Sidebar content*/}
          </div>
          <div className="span10">
            {/*Body content*/}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```